# Multiple Ajax Call - Passing Value From One To Next

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I need to make multiple AJAX calls, each one returning a value that the next one will need. I am aware that AJAX doesn't work like this necessarily as it's asynchronous.

I've read about Callbacks, Promises, Async Utility and by using the Success in a AJAX call, just not sure what to do.

Basically, I have to make about 8 different calls to a database, and am using JQuery/AJAX to make the calls.

What's the best/proper method to accomplish this?

Comment: This depends entirely on what you're doing? What data is being sent, what data is received, what data is needed for the next call, do all the calls use the same URL etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I would argue that is simplest to digest would be to put each call in unique function, and call each function in the success callback. Promises might be more elegant, but a little harder to understand. So something like this:

```
call1(1);

function call1(valueNeeded){
    $.get(url,function(data){
        call2(data);
    });
}
function call2(valueNeeded){
    $.get(url,function(data){
        call3(data);
    });
}
function call3(valueNeeded){
    $.get(url,function(data){
        //Finished
    });
}
```

I don't argue this is the "best" method, but it's pretty simple. Call you function, and when the ajax completes, you fire the next function from the success callback. The success callback gets invoked when the call completed *successfully*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send two or more requests that must all finish in order to proceed then you can use the `$.when` method. It will wait until all the requests have finished before running the `.done` callback.

```
$.when(
    $.get("/user/123"),
    $.get("/user/123/profile")
) .done(function (user, profile) {
    console.log("Hello " + user.name + " (" + profile.email + ")");
});
```

If a request depends on a previous request then you can use the `.then` method:

```
$.get("/user/123").then(function (user) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.get("/profile/" + user.profile_id).done(function (profile) {
        deferred.resolve(user, profile);
    });
    return deferred;
}).done(function (user, profile) {
    console.log("Hello " + user.name + " (" + profile.email + ")");
});
```

Comment: This is probably a better answer as it dives a bit deeper into what Javascript can do for you with chaining, if not a little harder to a beginner to see and digest.